# cannot delete database mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to delete user from mysql database with this code

```php
if (isset($_POST['user_delete'])) {
    $key = $_POST['keyToDelete'];
    $check = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ". $key or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $result2 = $connection->query($query);
    if($result2->num_rows >0){
         $query_delete = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id =". $key or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    var_dump($query_delete);
} else {

}
```

but it don't want to delete my database. but the sql already right and I also got the id because I tried to var_dump it. please help what was wrong with my code

Comment: Well, that's not going to delete the entire database, it's only possibly going to delete a user. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You never execute the second query (which is the same as the first?). You also `die()` to the querystring, not the execution of the query.

Comment: "*I tried to delete __from__ mysql database*" I guess?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few issues here,

1. Your `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` is to the querystrings, not the actual queries. Besides, instead of manually checking for errors it's much better to configure to throw errors automatically. For this add the following line to the connection code:

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   ```
2. You attempt to delete it twice? Though the second query is never executed, you just define the querystring (and never run it).
3. `num_rows` is only usable on select-statements. You want `affected_rows` to check if the query actually deleted any data.
4. You're not using a prepared statement.

```php
if (isset($_POST['user_delete'])) {
    $key = $_POST['keyToDelete'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $key);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
        echo "Deleted ".$stmt->affected_rows." rows";
    } else {
        echo "No rows matched the criteria.";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: it's not good to hardcode the error reporting into the application code. Let me edit your code with the proper error reporting?

Comment: Also, quite unexpectedly, but (3) is not true, these functions are interchangeable

Comment: The error-handling was merely an example (and to nudge in the direction of "*don't display errors to the end-user*") - feel free to improve it.. I've never seen `num_rows` work on delete queries though? No mention of it in the manual either that I can recall - do you have a source for that?

Comment: My bad, it works the other way round only, [For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: So here is my take on the error reporting. first, it makes the code less bloated. Second, it makes error reporting more flexible, as it can be configured at the application level.

Comment: I tried to use that example statement. it has no error but it still not delete the data in database. so I tried to change the "?" statement with "$key" but it still no delete the data

Comment: If you added `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` at the top as suggested by YCS, then you would see any potential errors. Don't swap out the `?`, its a bounded placeholder, you bind it to `$key` in `bind_param()`. Which of the two `echo` statements are printed?

Comment: I take that keyToDelete from modal after I take the user_delete from button before the modal comes

Comment: it printed deleted -1 rows

Comment: So the query returns an error. Enable exceptions in MySQLi by adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` at the top of your code, then you will see the error.

Comment: oh I got the error it says "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_survey`.`mitra`, CONSTRAINT `mitra_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))" so is it means it can't be deleted?

Comment: It means that there are values in the `mitra` table that depend on the values you are trying to delete. So, either delete those first, or you can alter your foreign key to be `ON DELETE CASCADE` (so it deletes the rows in `mitra` when you delete the user). Alternatively `ON DELETE SET NULL` if that's possible.